# Proof of: $X$ is finite $\iff X$ is Tarski-finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am self-studying *Horst Herrlich, Axiom of Choice (Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 1876)*. In the fourth chapter, he deals with different definitions of *finite set*. Here is the classical one:

> **Definition 1.** A set $X$ is called *finite* if there exists a bijection $n \to X$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Otherwise it is called *infinite*.

Here is Tarski's (1924) definition:

> **Definition 2.** A set $X$ is called *Tarski-finite*, provided that each non-empty subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ contains a minimal element w.r.t. the inclusion order. Otherwise it is called *Tarski-infinite*.

The following holds:

> **Proposition.** Equivalent are:
>
> 1. $X$ is Tarski-finite.
> 2. If $\mathcal U \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ satisfies
>
>    a) $\emptyset \in \mathcal U$, and
>
>    b) $A \in \mathcal U$ and $x \in X$ imply $A \cup \{x\} \in \mathcal U$,
>
> then $X \in \mathcal U$.

The proof of the proposition is simple. But right after that, he writes:

> Observe that by Proposition, the definition of finiteness as given in Definition 1 is equivalent to the one in Definition 2.

No proof follows. The "Def.1 $\implies$ Def.2" part seems easy to me, but the converse doesn't. Would you help me with that? Please, note that we **do not** want to use AC (indeed, all this thing is about proving that the two definitions are equivalent even in ZF). Therefore, we can't even use that "$X$ infinite $\implies \aleph_0 \leq |X|$", since the latter is not a theorem of ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It seems to be quite known...
- p. 45, *Horst Herrlich, Axiom of Choice (Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 1876)*; 
- p. 100, *Suppes, P. _Axiomatic_Set_Theory_, Dover, New York: 1972*; 
- first definition, *De la Cruz, Omar. Finiteness and choice. Fundamenta Mathematicae 173(1)57-76, 2002.*; 
- comments, http://planetmath.org/finite;

If you want, the original Tarski's paper is *A. Tarski. Sur les ensembles finis. Fund. Math., 6:45–95, 1924.*, which can be found here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm6/fm619.pdf 
(don't know which definition he uses there, though)

Comment: I thought that you had meant the proposition as the definition to Tarski-finite. Jech uses in his AC book, and I agree with that use, that Tarski-finite is a slightly weaker condition (every linearly ordered $\cal U$ has a maximal/minimal element). The reason I find Jech's definition more apt is that I find no sense in giving a new name and then proving it is equivalent to a well known definition of finiteness. It's better to give a nicer definition for an intermediate definition.

Comment: does "weaker" means in this case that ZF $\not\vdash$ "every $(X, \leq)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathcal F, \subseteq)$ for some set $Y$ and $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$"?

Comment: No, that's easily provable by taking $\cal F$ to be the set of closed cones. Weaker in the sense that if we require $\cal U$ in the definition of Tarski finite to be linearly ordered by $\subseteq$ rather than arbitrary, then it is possible to have infinite sets which satisfy this without the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $X$ is infinite and let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of finite subsets of $X$. Now use the proposition.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Can you think such an elegant and short proof for the converse too?

Comment: The converse will (probably) involve some kind of induction principle, so I suppose it depends what you mean by 'elegant'.

Answer (score 4):

What you would like to do is to say something like "Pick some element $x_0\in X$ then by induction pick $x_{n+1}\in X_n=X\setminus\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$" then $\mathcal U=\{X_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of sets without a minimal element.

But this is impossible, since moving from the induction to the infinite sequence requires some choice.

But there is a guiding philosophy in many choiceless proofs: If you can't choose, take everything. So taking all the co-finite sets would work. There is no minimal co-finite set, since removing a single element from an infinite set gives an infinite set.

(I gave this exercise to my students last year, and after we talked about the axiom of choice we proved it again, in the simpler way.)

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks.

Comment: I hope this also illustrates a bit why assuming the axiom of choice you can reduce your checking to $\cal U$ which are linearly ordered by $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 0):

I am self-studying *Thomas Jech, Set Theory*. Exercises 1.2 - 1.13 of the chapter 1 leads the reader to prove the equivalence of finite and T-finite.

##### $\text{Some Definitions}$

- Inductiveness:
  $X$ is inductive if
  $\emptyset\in X $ and $(\forall x\in X) x\cup\{x\}\in X$.
- Natural numbers:
  $\mathbb{N} = \bigcap \{x: x \text{ is inductive}\}$.
- ⊂-maximal element: $u$ is a ⊂-maximal element of $X$ if
  $\neg[(\exists v\in X) u \subset v \wedge u\neq v]$.
- T-finite: $X$ is T-finite if every $x (x\subset P(X))$ has a ⊂-maximal element.

##### 1. $\textit{Finite} \rightarrow \textit{T-Finite}$.

Prove that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is Tarski finite. Then the conclusion follows from the fact that any set with a bijection with some T-finite set is T-finite.

To prove that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is T-finite, show that if $X$ is inductive, $$S=\{ {x \in X}: {x \text{ is transitive}} \wedge {x \notin x} \wedge {x \text{ is T-finite}}\}$$ is inductive (i.e., $x$ being transitive means $\forall y (y \in x \rightarrow y \subset x)$).

The sketch of the proof. Let $s\in S$. We need to show that $s\cup \{s\}$ is T-finite. Let $f: P(s)\rightarrow P(s\cup\{s\})$ be defined by $f(x)=x\cup \{s\}$. Show that $f$ is a bijection from ${P(s)=\{x\in P(s\cup\{s\}):s\notin x\}}$ to ${\text{Ran}(f)=\{x\in P(s\cup\{s\}):s\in x\}}$. Let $u\subset P(s\cup\{s\})$ be non-empty. If $u-P(s) = \emptyset$, then $u\subset P(s)$ and thus $u$ has a ⊂-maximal element. Otherwise $f_{-1}(u-P(s))\neq\emptyset$ has a ⊂-maximal element $m$ and show that $f(m)$ is a ⊂-maximal element of $u$.

##### 2. $\textit{T-Finite} \rightarrow \textit{Finite}$.

Show that any infinite set is Tarski infinite. If $S$ is infinite, consider the set
$$X = \{x\subset S: x \text{ is finite}\} \subset P(S)$$
Note that $\emptyset \in X \rightarrow X \neq \emptyset$.

If $u \in X$,
$S \notin X$
implies that
$u \neq S \wedge u\subset S$
and thus
$\exists s (s\in S \wedge s \notin u)$.
Let $v = u \cup \{s\} $.
Next, show that $v$ is finite
by extending the bijection between $u \sim n$ to $v \sim n+1$
for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Thus, $v\in X \wedge u \neq v \wedge u \subset v$.
We conclude that X doesn't have a ⊂-maximal element. Thus S is not T-finite.