# Minimal Definition of "Finite Set"

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, definition

Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, page 25 has this definition:

> For any postive integer $n$, let $J_n$ be the set whose elements are the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$.

> $A$ is finite if $A\sim J_n$ for some $n$ (the empty set is also considered to be finite)

Here $B\sim C$ means ``there exists a 1-1 mapping of $B$ onto $C$''.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) has the same definition:

> Formally, a set $S$ is called **finite** if there exists a bijection $f:S\rightarrow\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some natural number $n$.

**Question**: is it not sufficient to stipulate that the map be 1-1? Requiring also that the map be onto seems to be unnecessary, and it seems like best practice to make minimal definitions.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, it is only necessary to require that it is 1-1. But I am not sure whether it is the "best practice" to use minimal definitions, it would make proving theorems a little harder...

Comment: @Yanko To resolve that, I am thinking it would be best to just follow the definition immediately with a proposition that there exists an onto function from $S$ to $\{1,\ldots,n'\}$ with $n'\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Well that would work :-). It is a convention, I see your point but I also see why some people would prefer to avoid using a proposition over and over, it is a matter of taste so no point arguing about it haha

Comment: Sometimes minimal definitions are not the simplest or the easiest.  Saying a finite set one in which there is a bijection between $\{1,....,n\}$ and it is both formally valid and it is intuitive (it basically says you can count that it has $n$ elements).  Although saying that an injection that need not be surjective from $S$ to $1,....n$ is  for less intuiitive and is not as simple and there is no longer any concept of "how many elements does it have".

Comment: See this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878073/proof-of-x-is-finite-iff-x-is-tarski-finite

Comment: To further illustrate @user14111’s point, we *could* define a group as a pair $(G, \cdot)$, where (1) $\cdot$ is associative, and there is some $e \in G$ such that (2) $e$ is a right identity - $\forall x \in G (x \cdot e = x)$, and (3) right inverses exist - $\forall x \in G \exists y \in G (x \cdot y = e)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65239. This definition is shorter than the usual definition - defining $e$ to be a 2-sided identity and having 2-sided inverses - but I would certainly not argue it’s a better definition.

Comment: @MarkSaving That's the way I've been defining groups. Maybe it's just an aesthetic preference?

Comment: It might be considered even "simpler" to say "A set $S$ is infinite if an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$ exists. A set is finite if it is not infinite." No need for the choice of $J_n$ set at all.

Comment: @Gary You can define a group using only **one** axiom: $x / ((((x / x) / y) / z) / (((x / x) / x) / z)) = y$. Do you really think that it's a good idea to use **that** as the definition of group?

Comment: @aschepler Since we're trying to give a "simpler" definition of "finite set”, we can avoid defining "infinite set”: $S$ is finite if there's no injection from $\Bbb N$ to $S$

Comment: @jjagmath I like this definition of "finite set"! Can you explain the meaning of axiom in the definition of "group"? Maybe I would find this definition superior if I could understand it.

Comment: @aschepler This definition not only requieres classical logic to be equivalent to the standard one; it also requires countable choice.

Comment: @Gary I'm not aware of the details but you'll find them in "G. Higman and B. H. Neumann. Groups as groupoids with one law. Publicationes Mathematicae Debrecen, 2:215--227, 1952."

Comment: @MarkSaving Yeah, I was thinking it might run into Axiom of Choice issues. But it could be usable in some systems.

Answer (score 6):

If you accept classical logic, you can show that if there is some injective $f : S \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$, then $S$ is finite. Equivalently, every subset of a finite set is finite. However, if you do not accept classical logic, you cannot prove this.

By “classical logic”, I mean the principle that for all propositions $P$, $P \lor \neg P$. This principle is equivalent to a few others, like double negation elimination, proof by contrapositive, etc. Logic formulated without these principles is known as “constructive logic”.

It turns out that “every subset of a finite set is finite” is equivalent to classical logic. To see this, consider a proposition $P$. Then take the set $S = \{1 \mid P\}$. That is, $\forall x (x \in S \iff x = 1 \land P)$.

Clearly, $S$ is a subset of the finite set $\{1\}$, which is finite since it is in bijection with itself. Suppose $S$ is finite; take some $n$ such that there is a bijection $S \cong \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Because $n$ is a natural number, we know it is either zero, or at least 1. If $n$ is zero, then $S$ is empty; therefore, $\neg P$. And if $n$ is at least one, then there is some $x \in S$, meaning that $P$ holds. So we have established $P \lor \neg P$.

However, the following can be shown constructively:

> Consider $S \subseteq R$ where $R$ is finite, and suppose $\forall r \in R (r \in S \lor r \notin S)$. Then $S$ is finite.

Of course, with classical logic, the premise $\forall r \in R (r \in S \lor r \notin S)$ is automatically true. So classically, every subset of a finite set is finite.

One final point. There are a few reasons to be interested in constructive logic. The first is philosophical. Perhaps you don’t really believe $P \lor \neg P$ unless you know which one - $P$ or $\neg P$ - holds. Or perhaps you are a devotee of Brouwer and hold to some of his (admittedly strange) philosophical considerations about the nature of sequences and free choice.

But even if you strongly believe in classical logic, constructive logic is still incredibly useful. For example, any function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which can be defined constructively can also be constructively proved to be continuous. Similarly, if we can prove any proposition of the form $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \exists m \in \mathbb{N} (P(n, m))$ constructively, then there exists some computable function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that we can constructively prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (P(n, f(n)))$.

Constructive logic has many other applications, especially in algebraic geometry and topos theory. You don’t have to believe in it (or more precisely, to disbelieve in classical logic) to make full use of its fruits.